# Cannot create multiple objects of same name using ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am creating a website to host different menus from restaurants in my town. In the code below `Restaurant` is the establishment, `MenuSection` is a section such as Appetizers, Entrees, Desserts, etc... and `FoodItem` is a dish you can order belonging to one of the sections on the menu. I am trying to connect each `MenuSection` to a `Restaurant` and each `FoodItem` to a `MenuSection` and `Restaurant`. I thought this could be achieved using a `ForeignKey` since it is a many-to-one relationship.

Obviously, food sections and food items are going overlap between restaurants. I thought this would not be an issue but in my db I have two `Restaurant` objects, one already has a `MenuSection` named "Appetizers", I tried to give the second Restaurant a `MenuSection` named "Appetizers" and it will not let me do so, saying: "`MenuItem` with this `MenuSection` already exists." How can I fix this? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
from django.db import models


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name

class MenuSection(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(
        Restaurant,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    food_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.food_type


class MenuItem(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(
        Restaurant,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    MenuSection = models.ForeignKey(
        MenuSection,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    food_item = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.food_item
```

Answer (score 0):

You set your `ForeignKey`s as primary keys. I haven't tried it but I suppose it turns them into `OneToOneField`. Try to remove `primary_key=True` from `ForeignKey`'s definitions.

Also I noticed that you bind restaurant twice (in `MenuSection` and in `MenuItem`). You can set restaurant in `MenuSection` only and access it from `MenuItem`, e.g. `menu_item.MenuSection.restaurant`.

Comment: If i delete `primary_key=True` I get `no such column: core_menuitem.id` when I try to access the admin

Comment: Did you create new migrations and migrate db after removing primary_key param? `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`.

Also do not forget to specify your environment (python and django version, database)

Comment: yes I did these things, maybe because there are existing objects that had primary_key=true. It was saying something about having to provide a one time value for existing models

Comment: You might be added non-nullable column to DB. That's why it asked about one-time value.
Seems your models in question are not complete.